# What exactly happened with the parity bug in Nov-2017 to lose $300+ M?

Tags: parity, contract-debugging, bug

From my understanding, all I know is that ether got locked up in parity and there's no way to get it out. I'm not familar with parity, as I just use myetherwallet to store ether.

- Isn't parity just a node software like bitcoin core? Or is it a wallet?
- If its a smart contract that lives in the blockchain, isn't it immutable where it cannot be deleted?
- How did this bug get overlooked during a code audit? Assuming it was a simple bug that a newbie coder found and screwed up.
- What are some solutions to resolve this similar problem down the line?